# Do Chinese citizen need finland transit visa?

Tags: visas, germany, finland, chinese-citizens

I'm a Chinese.
I will start from Korea, transit Finland(transit time is about 3 hours) to Germany, Berlin. I already knew I must have Germany visa.
Must i have a Finland visa? i just am going to transit in Finland without getting away Finland airport.

Comment: Finland and Germany are in the same "Country" for border purposes, so they use the same visa. You enter in Finland (that's where you clear Immigration) and then continue on a "domestic" flight to Germany.